# Rails 3: Model.all.count always returns 1 in after_create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I want to check in `after_create` if the newly created record is the first one that meets some condition. So I want to be able to check, `Model.where(...some condition...).count > 1`, in an `after_create` callback. However, Rails will not allow this for some reason and I can't find any explanations why. If I query, `Model.all.count`, in `after_create`, it always returns 1, and the one record is the one I just created. If I execute raw SQL in the after_create method then I can retrieve the correct information. Why can't I perform the query using `Model.where(...)`?

Edit:

In response to questions below. There are no errors messages. Below is the class and an example of the logged output. I feel like it must be something stupid I'm overlooking, I appreciate the help.

```
class ExperiencePhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :experience, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :photo


  after_create :set_cover_photo

  def self.find_or_create(params)
    where(params).first_or_create
  end


  protected

  def set_cover_photo
    logger.debug self.inspect
    logger.debug ExperiencePhoto.all.inspect
    logger.debug ExperiencePhoto.all.count.to_s
    logger.debug ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from experience_photos")[0].inspect

  end
```

end

calling this:

```
ExperiencePhoto.find_or_create(photo_id: photo_id, experience_id: self.id)
```

results in this output:

```
#<ExperiencePhoto id: 183, experience_id: 93, photo_id: 106>
[#<ExperiencePhoto id: 183, experience_id: 93, photo_id: 106>]
1
{"count"=>"168"}
```

Comment: Can you share that model

Comment: Can you also share the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What SQL does the log show for `ExperiencePhoto.all.count` ?

I don't know for sure, but I would guess it's because `set_cover_photo` is called with the scope of the previous `where`.

Try wrapping it in [unscoped](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/unscoped):

```
def set_cover_photo
  ExperiencePhoto.unscoped do
    logger.debug self.inspect
    logger.debug ExperiencePhoto.all.inspect
    logger.debug ExperiencePhoto.all.count.to_s
    logger.debug ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from experience_photos")[0].inspect
  end
end
```

Comment: yes! so the "where" scope was getting applied automatically in the "after_create" method. That is a bit surprising to me, I have some studying to do. Thanks!