# Missing relation in callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So I do have model **ModelA**, which *has_many* ModelB.
I've added a callback to ModelB, in which i wan't to check for some existing relations. Then in the callback I want to create a additional relation. (There is some more logic involved but just for simplicity I keept it that way)

The issue I'm facing right now is, that in the after_save callback is seams like existing relations are missing and the result is that i have duplicate entries in there.

I even tried to check the existence of the ModelB entry like `ModelB.where(some_attribute: "some value").exists?` and can't find it. I set a breakpoint in the after_save callback and at the same time opened a rails console, in the console i get the correct entries but not in the callback.

My guess would be that while in the callback I'm currently in a transaction, but why are there all relations missing? Also how could I escape this transaction?

```
class ModelA
  has_many :model_bs

  after_save do
    self.model_bs.where(some_attribute: "some value").first_or_create!
  end
end

class ModelB
  belongs_to :model_a
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473162/rails-3-model-all-count-always-returns-1-in-after-create-method), it seams like callbacks are executed within the scope of the where. So for it worked by executing the code of the callback inside a unscoped block.

```
class ModelA
  has_many :model_bs

  after_save do
    ModelB.unscoped do
      self.model_bs.where(some_attribute: "some value").first_or_create!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would really reconsider if callbacks are really the best way to handle this. You might want to look at the service object or interactor pattern.